# How to set image from database

Tags: android

Friend's,
       I have a problem in fetching image from database,when i store the image url in database has Blob data type in sqlite,
where the code for inserting is

DefaultHttpClient mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

```
                HttpGet mHttpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.dashfire.com/jackrobie/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/97x144/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/a/l/alexander_1_1_1.jpg");

                HttpResponse mHttpResponse = mHttpClient.execute(mHttpGet);

                if (mHttpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {

                  HttpEntity entity = mHttpResponse.getEntity();

                    if ( entity != null) {

                      // insert to database

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(JR_Constants.NAME, name1);
                values.put(JR_Constants.PRICE, price);
                values.put(JR_Constants.IMAGE_97, EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity));
```

the values being seemed in the table has after the above,
_id | name     | image_97                        | price
1     mss       & - (its like an alpha symbol)        $115.00
2     sss       & -    "                              $120.00

the code for table creation here...
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
       try{
      db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" (" 
              +_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," 
              + NAME+" TEXT," 
              + IMAGE_97+" BLOB,"
              + PRICE+" TEXT);");
      Log.v("JR_Data","table created");
      }catch(Exception e){
          Log.v("JR_Data","exception in table created");

## }

## i need to know the format of byte array in table is it simply looks like alpha symbol or some thing else,....from my table.

below the code i fetch the image from db has follows

```
            ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.jr_lb_list_icon);
```

line 1.             byte[] bb = c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex(JR_Constants.IMAGE_97));
                  try {
                myImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bb, 0, bb.length));
                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Error1 " +e);
                }

From above line 1. mentioned where it contains JR_Constants.IMAGE_97  its string constant.

when fetch and set the image from table it throws an nullpointer exception..what is actually wrong with it,and help me to  get image by using above code....

**and i'm doing above process when the device is in offline**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you mentioned

```
 "ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.jr_lb_list_icon);"
```

this code...please check the ID "**jr_lb_list_icon**" is imageview or otherthings...
i think this id is not for image view...

Comment: @hi,i need your help on implementing listview with footer,where i got the view as well with footer at bottom,here the problem is where the footer hava click event to parse next page url data to bind on list view,where parsing to be good,but the list being stay back with previous page content,where the newly parsed data is not being added with list view,what is the problem,how can i fix it.just refer my question i posted with layout,i hope you may help me to get what i needed. thanks in advance